# How Erlang Mnesia Distribution Works

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, mnesia

I am getting through the online examples, and can already use mnesia ram copies and also connect them, but I am a bit confused on a couple of things.

1:  Does the starter node (the one who creates the schema), only have the local schema?  (for example, in root folder = Mnesia.name@ip)

I ask because on another node, I can simply start mnesia, and change_config(extra_db_nodes, [node]), and automatically get all the data that is on the starting node.

This seems weird to me, what happens if all nodes go down?  This means starter node needs to be ran first before you can do anything.

2:  There seems to be a lot of different ways to connect nodes, and to copy the tables ...  Could I get a list of different ways to do this, and their impacts?

3:  From the first question, after calling change_config, how can you know that its finished downloading all the data before you can start to use it?  For example, if someone connects to the node, and you check if they are already online, they might be connected to another node and you dont get that data during the check.

4:  After connecting to a node, are you automatically connected to all nodes?  And does it automatically update your local ram copies without doing anything?  How does it assure synchronization when reading, and writing?  Do I have to do anything special?

And about question 1 again -- couldn't you have a node process running that holds the local schema, and use this node to connect all nodes together?  And if possible could you forbid mnesia from copying ram copies to this node process?

I know this is a lot, so thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your questions, but you can check out [Erlang Performance Lab](http://www.erlang.pl/) which might help you understand how some operations in Mnesia works by visualizing the messages between different nodes.